# PHPdoc does not detect object (and other properties)

Tags: php, object, phpdoc

I am trying to create a PHPdocument for my project with the correct information.
I am trying to create information for objects, created inside a method of a class. 
Sadly, PHPdoc does not recognize my object inside my function.

The code is as following:

```
class app_controll
{
/**
  * This function starts the application. All the functionality starts here.
  * @return Objects Method returns all the objects and functions needed to build a page.
  */
public function start_application() 
     {
     /**
      * The domain_controll object contains domain information.
      * @var object domain_controll
      */
     $oDomain_controll = new domain_controll();
     }
}
```

What am I defining wrong?

Comment: It this working? /* @var $oDomain_controll domain_controll */

Comment: Sadly not, it seems as though the entire object is not detected by PHPdoc.
Normally a variable always shows in the document, even though there is no comments for it. 

This object does not even show in the documentation, similar to all the properties defined inside the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked the question on Github. I got a response from James Pittman:

> In this case, $oDomain_controll would be an internal variable, visible
>   only within the start_application() function. There would be no reason
>   to include it in API documentation, because it's not usable or
>   viewable by a consumer of the app_controll class. If you want to make
>   it a public member of the app_controll class, you should declare it
>   outside of the start_application() function:

```
class app_controll()
{
    /**
     * The domain_controll object contains domain information.
     * @var domain_controll
     */
    public $oDomain_controll;

    public function start_application()
    {
        $oDomain_controll = new domain_controll();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answer James :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class app_controll
{
/**
  * This function starts the application. All the functionality starts here.
  * @return Objects Method returns all the objects and functions needed to build a page.
  */
public function start_application() 
     {
     /**
      * The domain_controll object contains domain information.
      * @var $oDomain_controll domain_controll
      */
     $oDomain_controll = new domain_controll();
     }
}
```

Usage is : **@var objectName className**

Comment: This doesn't work either with my model. /** @var $oDomain_controll app_controll blabla*/